# Terminology and notation for complicated roots

Tags: polynomials, notation, roots

I know that $a^*$ is the second largest root of the following equation:

$$32\left(\sqrt{50-10\sqrt{5}}\right)a^3-\frac{48}{5}(5+\sqrt{5}) \pi a + 8\sqrt{10(5+\sqrt{5})} = 0  $$

Note that $\pi$ is the constant, not a variable.

> Q1: What would you call such an equation?

Perhaps a cubic equation with irrational coefficients?

I also want to express this as neatly as possible, maybe writing something like:
$$a^* = \text{Root}\left(32\left(\sqrt{50-10\sqrt{5}}\right)a^3-\frac{48}{5}(5+\sqrt{5}) \pi a + 8\sqrt{10(5+\sqrt{5})} = 0,2\right).$$

> Q2: Does an operator (i.e. symbol denoting a mathematical operation, not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics))) like that exist?

I'm sure some will think it more elegant to just define $a^*$ as I did to start this question, and others will think it better to give the solution in radicals. The problem with the former is that, while more aesthetically appealing, it's a little more difficult to use in tables and perhaps a bit annoying if used repetitively. The problem with the latter is that it is very messy (relative to the operator approach I try above), even after simplifying as much as possible. That's why I'd prefer to define $a^*$ with an operator if an appropriate one exists.

> Note: An ideal answer would answer both Q1 and Q2. It may be that such an answer would simply be "Yes and no, respectively." But, if that is the case, I would appreciate any commentary on how you would recommend representing the root in a journal article.

Comment: Q2 : what do you mean exactly by "operator"?

Comment: @paf I meant it as _a symbol to denote a mathematical operation_, not a mapping between vector spaces and modules. Thanks for pointing out that potential confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering the questions, it is desirable to convert the equation to the foreseeable mind. In this case we use the golden section Mauger constant
$$\varphi=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2\approx1.618,$$
then
$$\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}2=\dfrac1\varphi,$$
and original equation takes the form
$$\dfrac{64\cdot5^{3/4}}{\sqrt\varphi}a^3-\dfrac{96\pi\varphi}{\sqrt5}a+16\cdot5^{3/4}\sqrt\varphi = 0,$$
or
$$4a^3-\dfrac{6\pi\varphi^{3/2}}{5^{5/4}}a+\varphi=0.$$
Number $\pi$ is irrational (transcendental), multiplication and division on rational and irrational numbers does not change the situation. Consequently,

$$\boxed{\text{Q1: yes, it's a cubical equation with irrational (transcendental) coefficients.}}$$

Both [the original](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=32%5Cleft(%5Csqrt%7B50-10%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%5Cright)a%5E3-%5Cfrac%7B48%7D%7B5%7D(5%2B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D)%20%5Cpi%20a%20%2B%208%5Csqrt%7B10(5%2B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D)%7D%20%3D%200) and [changed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4a%5E3-%5Cdfrac%7B6%5Cpi%5Cvarphi%5E%7B3%2F2%7D%7D%7B5%5E%7B5%2F4%7D%7Da%2B%5Cvarphi%3D0) forms give the same result.

For an elegant answer to the second question, we introduce [the coefficient](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7D%2F%7B5%5E%7B5%2F8%7D%7D)
$$\mu=\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi}\varphi^{3/4}}{5^{5/8}}\approx1.315,$$
then equation takes the form
$$4a^3-3\mu^2a+\varphi=0.\qquad(1)$$

The precise mathematical formula for recording the second-highest root is unknown to me. At the same time, the Mathcad package required value is given a convenient and understandable expression of the form
$$\boxed{\text{Q2a:}\qquad
a^* = \mathrm{polyroots}\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\varphi\\
-3\mu^2\\
4
\end{pmatrix}
\right)_1}$$
The highest degree coefficient places below others and the result of polyroots() function is ordered vector of roots wherein the root with the greatest real part has index $0.$

Also the equation $(1)$ can be presented in the form
$$4\left(\dfrac{a}\mu\right)^3-3\dfrac{a}\mu=-\dfrac\varphi{\mu^3},$$
or
$$\mathrm T_3\left(\dfrac{a}\mu\right) = -\dfrac\varphi{\mu^3},$$
where
$$\mathrm T_3(x)=4x^3-3x$$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.
Note that
$$\left|-\dfrac\varphi{\mu^3}\right|\approx 0.711 <1,$$
so we can use the Chebyshev polynomial in form
$$\mathrm T_3(x) = \cos(3\arccos x)$$
and get the equation
$$\cos\left(3\arccos \left(\dfrac{a}\mu\right)\right) = -\dfrac\varphi{\mu^3}$$
with the ordered roots as in Mathcad
$$a_k=\mu\cos\left(\dfrac13\arccos\dfrac\varphi{\mu^3}+\dfrac{2k-1}3\pi\right),\quad k=0,1,2.$$
[Thus](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cvarphi%5E%7B3%2F4%7D%7D%2F%7B5%5E%7B5%2F8%7D%7D*%5Ccos(1%2F3%20arccos(%5Cvarphi%2F(%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cvarphi%5E%7B3%2F4%7D%7D%2F%7B5%5E%7B5%2F8%7D%7D)%5E3%7D)%2B%7B2*1-1%7D%2F3*pi)), 
$$\boxed{\text{Q2b:}\quad a^*=\mu\cos\left(\dfrac13\arccos\dfrac\varphi{\mu^3}+\pi/3\right)}$$

Comment: Where does 'no' for Q1 comes from? Yes, the coefficients are transcendental (one of them), but they are irrational as well. As for the rest of the answer, I like it, +1

Comment: @YuriyS Of course, you're right. I would like to emphasize that the roots of the equation are not algebraic numbers, but did it badly.

Comment: Thanks for this -- this is a neat approach and I like that you've illuminated a connection to the Golden ratio constant!

Comment: @Shane I like it too)

Answer (score 1):

Q1 : yes, it's a cubic equation with irrational coefficients.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/666983)

Comment: This is precisely an answer to Q1 which asks "what would you call such an equation?" and to which I answer "this is a cubic equation with irrational coefficients".